# Is it possible to lose some directories when upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: upgrade, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Last day I upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop to Ubuntu 12.04. I was running a KVM virtual about 7 machines and managed by virt-manage software.

Anyway when I finished upgrading I found that virt-manager is not working. So I had to reconfigure it again and install some other missing packages that was deleted! Eventually, I managed to solve this issue.

Then I started to restore my virtual machines. I restored 2 machines without any problems. The third and fourth ones (Windows) made a check disk that lasted more that 6 hours but finally it worked. Other machines I can't find their attached hard disks. I don't know what happened but I can't find those files.

1. Does upgrading delete files?
2. Is there anyway to restore those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes sure you will loose all softwares that are not in the box of the new version which is ubuntu 12.04
for example if you installed `virt-manager` on top of ubuntu 11.10 you will loose at least the `libvirtd` service and its configuration files

Comment: can i restore the deleted files

Comment: unfortunately they will be lost. So you need a third party programs for recovery. Check r-linux